# Searching replacement for CM8870

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am searching for a functionally compatible replacement for the CM8870.

Would the HT9170 or MC145436 be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

The HT9170 is a compatible replacement for the CM8870. They are both DTMF Receivers. They are pin compatible (18 pins) and the HT9170 has a wider operating voltage (2.5 to 5.5V), while the CM8870 works with 5V supply.

The MC145436 is also a DTMF Receiver, but is not pin compatible with CM8870 or HT9170. The MC145436 has 14 pins instead of 18 of the other two.

Here are links to their datasheets: [HT9170](http://www.ece.usu.edu/ece_store/spec/HT9170.pdf), [CM8870](http://www.biltek.tubitak.gov.tr/gelisim/elektronik/dosyalar/18/ics8870.pdf), [MC145436](http://www.telephonetribute.com/pdf/MC145436A.pdf)